# Facing issues with react-native-webview

Tags: webview, react-native

I have a code written in react-native wherein I'am using a webview to render a website. The URL for same is here
https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link.html?isWebview=true&key=test_key&env=tartan&product=connect&longtail=true&selectAccount=true&clientName=plaid.
 When I try to hit this URL, I'am getting Webkit Error domain, Error Code 101. I did research on this before posting the question here. But none of them gave me a workaround.

Below is the code.

```
 <WebView
    source={{uri:'https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link.html?isWebview=true&key=test_key&env=tartan&product=connect&longtail=true&selectAccount=true&clientName=Plaid'}}
  />
```

Please excuse brevity. Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Can you add more info about the error you are getting? Who is giving the error? Perhaps a screen shot?

Comment: That URL seems to be redirecting to a `plaidlink://` URL, which may not be supported on your device, or maybe not supported by the Webview, I don't know

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble with this as well, and it looks like the Plaid docs may have a typo in the example URL under "[Link WebView Initialization URL](https://plaid.com/docs/api/#webview-integration)". Try using the `isWebView` parameter instead of `isWebview`. Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to isWebview=false. It's working for me. Then catch the messages thrown by the webview in onMessage callback

I don't know why you send those many parameters, for example longtail, i can't find any reference to it.

This is my URL https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link.html?isWebview=false&key=${PLAID_CONFIG.public_key}&clientName=${PLAID_CONFIG.clientName}&env=${PLAID_CONFIG.env}&product=${products}`

Also, as far as I know env should be one of sandbox, production, development.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but worth noting a [`react-native-plaid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-plaid)
 [`npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/) package that may address the issue in question.